# 2 outputs in Keras model but only one with missing value?

Tags: python, keras, missing-data, tf.keras, loss-function

I'd like to model two variables simultaneously using the same features at the input layer (a feed-forward network), but there are missing values **in one of them**. I'm wondering if there is a way to mask the missing values when computing loss functions in Keras, bacause I don't want to delete Target 1 values at the index of missing Taregt 2 values during preprocessing.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As of now, I found that the best answer can be lumping two outputs into one and add an extra **one-hot code** to inputs to include whether the output is target 1 or 2. I found it works great for my study.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can do some data processing and either drop the NaN values or fill them with the average value.
You can have a look at this https://towardsdatascience.com/data-preprocessing-concepts-fa946d11c82

Comment: As I said I don't want to delete known values for Target 1. Theoretically, there should not be an issue with ignoring NaNs in the loss function. I would like to know the technical way of doing it.

Comment: Yes so you can use average values in that case

Comment: Yeah but that is not an intuitive way